# What is wrong in these Perl statements

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu

```
s/\[\[[a-z\-]*:[^\]]*\]\]//g;   
s/\[\[[^\|\]]*\|/[[/g;  # remove {{icons}} and {tables} from xml script    
s/{{[^}]*}}//g;
```

Error at second line is

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by 
<-- HERE in m/{{ <-- HERE [^}]*}}/ at clean.pl line 34.
```

Comment: The error refers to `m/{{` but none of the expressions uses `m//`; they're all `s///`.  And the message mentions line 34.  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and show the error for the MCVE (with the correct line number).

Comment: If it referred to the third line, then you need to use `s/\{\{[^}]*\}\}//g;`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan correctly pointed out, the issue is in your third line.
Here, regex would consider your brackets as operators, hence you need to 'escape' them (using '\') if they are actually part of your string.